# Pushing integers to an array keeps the order but pushing objects don't

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have a question that I cannot figure out.

This is my JSON

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "resources": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "qty": 5,
       "text": "text1"
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "qty": 5,
       "text": "text2"
     },
     {
       "id": 3,
       "qty": 5,
       "text": "text3"
     },
     {
       "id": 4,
       "qty": 3,
       "text": "text4"
     }]
}
```

I loop through the json.resources with a simple for loop, like the one below

```
var new_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.resources.length; i++) {
        var qty = json.resources[i].qty;
        for (var j = 0; j < qty; j++) {

            var new_resource = {
                id: json.resources[i].id,
                text: json.resources[i].text
            };

            new_array.push(new_resource);
        };
    };
```

This loops wants to take the property "qty" of my "resources" stored in the JSON, and save an entry in a new array (called new_array) for each "qty" i.e. if qty is 5 I want to push to new_array the same resource 5 times.

When I try to output new_array, the order of the items is not what I expected, and changes every time I refresh the page. I expected to fin within the first 5 positions of the array all the elements with id = 1 and text = text1. It never happened.

If I use the same method to push just the "id" property to the array, and not a whole object, the result is what I expected:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

Is there a reson why do I get such different behaviours? Is there something I am missing that I should consider further?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could not reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/tcxqsut2/

Comment: works for me.  how are you "outputting" new_array?

Comment: Keep in mind that since javascript is an interpretive language a lot of things get pretty fuzzy.  For example, there isn't much difference between a regular array and a key-valued array.  This points back to what @karina said in "how are you 'outputting' new_array?"   especially if you are using a foreach or similar loop.

Comment: I am just console.logging the array once it has been populated. It prints the array of objects that I can open up in chrome inspector. I am using Chrome latest version. Could it be some sort of "visual representation problem" related to the browser inspector? Maybe the array is just fine?

Comment: Dang.. it's some kind of weird visual representation in the console log.. I tried to append a li item containing the text property to an ul element, and it printed the texts in the correct order.. Thank you guys, never trust console.log apparently :<